# Not loading entire txt file into dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text-files

Im a python noob to get that out of the way and I am writing these functions using the OOP method just a FYI. My save_roster function works correctly, it saves  all of the dictionary player roster to my text file 'roster'. I confirmed this by looking in the text file making sure it is all there. Now when I go to load_roster function it only loads the first key and value and none of the rest and I cant figure out why. Any help as to how I can load  the entire dictionary or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
def save_roster(player_roster):
    print("Saving data...")
    file = open("roster.txt", "wt")
    import csv
    w = csv.writer(open("roster.txt", "w"))
    for key, val in player_roster.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
    print("Data saved.")
    file.close()

def load_roster(player_roster):
    print("Loading data...")
    import csv
    file = open("roster.txt", "rt")
    for key, val in csv.reader(file):
        player_roster[key] = eval(val)
        file.close()
        print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
        return (player_roster)
```

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help below. I just replied to your lower comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return (player_roster)` statement is inside of the `for` loop, which means it only reads the first line before returning. You need to put the statement outside the loop like so:

```
def load_roster(player_roster):
    print("Loading data...")
    import csv
    file = open("roster.txt", "rt")
    for key, val in csv.reader(file):
        player_roster[key] = eval(val)
    file.close()
    print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
    return (player_roster)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when  pull those instructions outside of the for loop I get the error (for key, val in csv.reader(file):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Is there an empty line in your roster.txt? Because that causes that error when I test your code

Comment: Yes there is an empty inbetween each entry inside of the text file.

Comment: The csv can only handle lines in the pattern you set, so if there are empty lines it doesn't fit that pattern so it will throw that error. So all you need to do is get rid of all the empty lines. Sorry for the long response time